# c# how to set the code run at final

Tags: c#, asynchronous, final

I need to set the line of code to run after everything has finish run. Anyone know how to do that?

```
private void ScanBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var folder = @"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\LenzOCR\WindowsFormsApplication1\ImageFile";

            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo;
            FileInfo[] files;
            directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            files = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            var processImagesDelegate = new ProcessImagesDelegate(ProcessImages2);
            processImagesDelegate.BeginInvoke(files, null, null);


            **//HERE IS THE LINE OF CODE THAT NEED TO BE RUN AFTER EVERYTHING FINISH RUN
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\TempFolder\tempPic.jpg");**
        }

        private void ProcessImages2(FileInfo[] files)
        {
            var comparableImages = new List<ComparableImage>();

            var index = 0x0;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (exit)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var comparableImage = new ComparableImage(file);
                comparableImages.Add(comparableImage);
                index++;
            }

            index = 0;

            similarityImagesSorted = new List<SimilarityImages>();
            //MessageBox.Show("here"+singleFileInfo.FullName);
            var fileImage = new ComparableImage(singleFileInfo);

            for (var i = 0; i < comparableImages.Count; i++)
            {
                if (exit)
                    return;

                var destination = comparableImages[i];
                var similarity = fileImage.CalculateSimilarity(destination);
                var sim = new SimilarityImages(fileImage, destination, similarity);
                similarityImagesSorted.Add(sim);
                index++;
            }

            similarityImagesSorted.Sort();
            similarityImagesSorted.Reverse();
            similarityImages = new BindingList<SimilarityImages>(similarityImagesSorted);

            var buttons =
                new List<Button>
                    {
                        ScanBT
                    };

            if (similarityImages[0].Similarity > 70)
            {
                con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CharacterImage;Integrated Security=True";
                con.Open();

                String getFile = "SELECT ImageName, Character FROM CharacterImage WHERE ImageName='" + similarityImages[0].Destination.ToString() + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(getFile, con);
                SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                while (rd2.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        string getText = rd2["Character"].ToString();
                        Action showText = () => ocrTB.AppendText(getText);
                        ocrTB.Invoke(showText);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No character found!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }
```

Comment: After your asynchronous call is finished, fire off an event ProcessCompleted on the main thread. Or use a BackgroundWorker instead... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: @mservidio You are writing to him as if he knew what he is doing. ;-).

Comment: remember to accept the correct answer when you find one.

Answer (score 1):

How about move the line of code to delete the file to the end of the process images method?

Comment: You're going to need to change the method, so that it doesn't have multiple exit points (which it currently does) if you go with this approach :)  Although truth be told, I can't see where exit comes from...

Comment: Very good point, i missed the return statements. You could wrap the delete command in a method and add before each return statement.

Answer (score 1):

- Run the code inside ProcessImages2 method in a **BackgroundWorker.DoWork(...)**
- Substitute *ProcessImagesDelegate.BeginInvoke(files, null, null)* with **worker.RunWorkerAsync(...)**
- Trap the event **RunWorkerCompleted** and execute there the **File.Delete(...)**.

In this way your main thread is free to be refreshed and used by end-user.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the method like below the call will block until ProcessImages2 is completed.

```
var processImagesDelegate = new ProcessImagesDelegate(ProcessImages2);  
IAsyncResult result = processImagesDelegate.BeginInvoke(files, null, null);
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
**//HERE IS THE LINE OF CODE THAT NEED TO BE RUN AFTER EVERYTHING FINISH RUN   
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\TempFolder\tempPic.jpg");
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but in this case main thread will be locked waiting the other thread to finish. If main thread is a GUI this cannot be good for user...